# How to get the name of a person who has maximum age using UNIX commands

Tags: linux, unix, max

I would like to get the name of the person who has maximum age in a unix data file. How can I do this?

```
Rob,20
Tom,30
```

I tried this as below but it gives me only max age.

```
awk -F"," '{print $2}' age.txt | sort -r | head -1
```

Comment: Learn to use [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk) - i.e. GNU awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file | awk -F, '{print $2,$1;}' | sort -n | tail -n1
30 Tom
$ cat file | awk -F, '{print $2,$1;}' | sort -n | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2;}'
Tom
```

Answer (score 1):

Try perhaps

```
awk -F, '{if (maxage<$2) { maxage= $2; name=$1; };} END{print name}' \
      age.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

traditional:

```
sort -t, -nr +1 age.txt | head -1 | cut -d, -f1
```

POSIXy:

```
sort -t, -k2,2nr age.txt | head -n 1 | cut -d, -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can easily do this using below command

```
echo -e "Rob,20\nTom,30\nMin,10\nMax,50" | sort -t ',' -rk 2 | head -n 1
```

[image]

Please comment in case of any issues.